# What does the 'Strong' label mean exactly in Puzzle and Dragons?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

I was playing Puzzle and Dragons in the special Wednesday dungeon of the masks (int) and on the 4th and 5th wave when they show the masks that are harder to beat. Sometimes depending on how much hp I have they'll have a strong indicator when I enter that wave and then it goes away.

In the past seeing that resulted in me thinking and experiencing the fact that if I don't kill it before its turn comes it will one hit KO me (unless I use a shield ability)

So, there were two masks both with the strong indicator, they both went on different turns, one would attack me in 8 turns and another in 7 turns.

I had no shield increasing or attack decreasing abilities and when the first one attacked I was left with almost no hp... BUT I survived?? I managed to beat them after that since I got them low enough by then but I was wondering. Did it mean that both of them would kill me if they both went at the same time? I was wondering if someone could explain this to me in more detail.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Strong" typically means that their attack is very close to (or exceeds) your team's HP.  Thus, you are highly likely to lose if that monster is successful in attacking you.  It's not a guaranteed 1-hit KO, but it's close enough that you should be worried.

The experts on the [PAD forum](http://puzzleanddragonsforum.com/archive/index.php/thread-858.html) seem to corroborate my personal experience on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

"Strong" means their standard unblocked attack will knock out **at least** 75% of your current maximum HP.  That's what it says in the [game mechanics](http://pad.wikia.com/wiki/Game_Mechanics) section at pad.wikia.com and seems to jive with my experience.

At least early on you can see this when an enemy gains the 'strong' label after charging for their next attack.  I've had it happen to me when my leader that gives 2x HP gets bound and my maximum HP dropped from 22k to 11k and the monster hits for 10k.  When the binding wore off, the 'strong' label disappeared even though I still only had 11k hp.